# How to apply the "collapse" style to a TabularInline object in the admin area?

Tags: django, django-admin

When defining the fieldsets for the add view and change view for a model in the admin area, it's possible to minimise a section like this:

```
class User(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('First Heading', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('one', 'two')
        }),
        ('Second Heading', {
            'fields': ('three',)
        }),
    )
```

The important bit being `'classes': ('collapse',)`.

I've added a TabularInline object to one of the admin screens. Basically when I'm editing a User I can see a tabulated list of his friends.

I'd like the TabularInline object to initially be collapsed, similar to  `'classes': ('collapse',)`.

I've tried adding a fieldsets tuple to the TabularInine class, but it doesn't make a difference:

```
class Friends(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Friend
    fieldsets = (
        ('Friends', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('name',)
        }),
    )
```

Can you help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. This only works in Django 1.10

Add `classes = ['collapse']` to the Inline class.

So in my case:

```
class Friends(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Friend
    classes = ['collapse']
```